# efficiently finding rows in a multi-gigabyte dataset

Tags: python

I have two datasets formatted as follows:

infile1:

```
1       742429  SNP_A-1909444   T       C       .       .       PR      GT      0/0     0/0     0/0     
1       767376  SNP_A-2237149   G       A       .       .       PR      GT      0/0     0/0     0/0 
1       769185  SNP_A-4303947   A       G       .       .       PR      GT      0/0     ./.     0/0
```

infile2:

```
1   742428  742430  rs3094315   SNP_A-1909444   C   T   +
1   769184  769186  rs4040617   SNP_A-4303947   A   G   -
```

If data in column 3 from inifle1 and data in column 5 from infile 2 agree, and last column in infile2 == "-" then, I want to switch values from columns 2,4,5 from infile1 to those in columns 2,6,7 from infile2.

I can do it with some if statements, however files are quite big (several gigs), so it's absolutely infeasible, thus, what is the best way in python to carry it out?

EDIT:

```
for line in infile1:
    line = line.split()
    for row in infile2:
        row = row.split()
        if line[4] == row[6]:
            if row[-1] == "-":
                line[3] == row[3]
                line[5] == row[7]
                line[6] == row[8]
```

I can read one file as a list of tuples, but doesn't speed things up, as it's going from start to end of the files every time it iterates.

Comment: the problem relates to file management more than to python. It's the algorithm that matters. Please show your ideas and attempts in python

Comment: You should probably use an actual database instead of two flat text files. There are limitations to flat files with no indexing, you are seeing a biggie. Module sqlite3 is built into Python and is extremely robust, especially as a replacement for flat files.

Comment: Your code is not only scanning the entire list, it's rereading file2 for _each_ row of file1. Read file2 once and keep it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in python, you need to index the rows of file2 by SNP number; you can do that with a dictionary:

```
rows2 = [ line.split() for line in infile2 ]
data2 = dict( (row[4], row) for row in rows2 )

for line in infile1:
    r = line.split()
    row2 = data2.get(r[2])
    if row2 and row2[-1] == "-":
        <make the replacement>
```

This assumes that the SNP ids in file 2 are unique, of course.

But if the files are truly too big to hold in memory, or if you have a lot of this to do, the right approach is to store them as two database tables. The transformation you describe can be carried out with a single SQL query. From python, you could simply write them into an sqlite3 database-- no external servers or software to install.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better specify a better data format. From the example data, it appears the data is fixed-width columns, but your code uses `split()`, which implies that one may treat it as a space-delimited "CSV" (if your data really doesn't have spaces in each cell).

Then, you'd do better to translate your data to a database. A database has specially crafted algorithms do deal with what you want, which is a join and select method, followed by update operations. Database optimizations apply, such as indexing by the SNP column, which may fasten joins.

If, however, you don't want to convert data, or if you want to convert-while-applying, you may check some other options. The first I'd look is the [Blaze ecosystem](http://blaze.pydata.org/). The [Blaze library](http://blaze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) itself may help you do out-of-core processing (which you need in case your files are as big as you say). You should also check if the Pandas database-like operations will work for you, such as [`join()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and indexing. In that case, you may try something like

```
dataset3 = dataset1.join(dataset2, "SNP")
dataset3 = dataset3[dataset3.plus_minus_column=='-']
len1 = len(dataset1.columns)-1  # maybe -2?
dataset1[3,5,6,dataset3.index] = dataset3[:,(3+len1,7+len1,8+len1)]
```

**after** you've done proper indexing.

You may also try to use [`update()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
dataset1.update(dataset2[dataset2.plus_minus_column=='-',(2,6,7)])
```

**Beware** that these code snippets are not tested (just got it out of memory) and I don't really know if it will give you any performance boost, if they work at all.